# Wrong date from java GET

Tags: angular, date, jakarta-ee

I am creating a Customer management using Angular for my Frontend and Java EE as my backend. Issue is Posting and Getting the correct date of birth. The post seems to be working fine.

```js
countryCode US
dateOfBirth 1998-08-05
firstName Eva
gender F
lastName Egger
```

and in my Database the date is added just like that, but for some reason I when I GET the data, the date is a completely different format.

```js
gender F
dateOfBirth 902268000000
firstName Eva
lastName Egger
countryCode US
```

Could it be that on the java side I have to convert java.sql.Date  to java.util.Date? but that doesn't quite make sense either because i did not have to do any conversion when I was doing the POST.

Comment: “java.sql.Date to java.util.Date” — both of those terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

> java.sql.Date to java.util.Date

Those terrible classes were supplanted years ago but the *java.time* classes.

## java.time

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate` class in Java. In your database, use a data type on your column akin to the SQL-standard `DATE`.

You have apparently used the **wrong type in your database**, something which combines a date with a time-of-day and possible with a time zone.

You have not shown us enough details for a proper solution. But likely you are **mixing in a time zone**, perhaps implicitly, when translating your date-only into date-time. Seems to be a time zone such as `America/Noronha`, `Atlantic/South_Georgia`, or `America/Miquelon`.

Date-time handling with JDBC and *java.time* has been covered many many many times, so **search Stack Overflow** to learn much more.

## Count from epoch

As for your mystery number, it appears to be a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

```
long input = 902_268_000_000L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( input ) ;
```

You can run this [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/5bBHmA).

> instant.toString(): 1998-08-04T22:00:00Z

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

> 1998-08-05
>
> i did not have to do any conversion when I was doing the POST

That YYYY-MM-DD is the default format used in SQL (and in ISO 8601 standard, by the way). So apparently you are sending plain strings to your database. Learn to use smart objects rather than dumb strings when interacting with your database.

As of JDBC 4.2 you can exchange *java.time* types with the database via `getObject` & `setObject` methods.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "1998-08-05" ) ;  // For a column of type `DATE`. 
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;  // For a column of type `DATE`.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because its converted to java date object when it comes from db and later on it is serialized into string timestamp. (probably) Paste it here https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ - just cut 3 zeros as those are miliseconds, and you will see

[image]